# Meteor utilities:avatar data

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, avatar

I'd like to use the utilities:avatar package, but I'm having some major reservations.

The docs tell me that I should publish my user data, like this:

```
Meteor.publish("otherUserData", function() {
var data = Meteor.users.find({
    }, {
        fields : {
            "services.twitter.profile_image_url_https" : true,
            "services.facebook.id" : true,
            "services.google.picture" : true,
            "services.github.username" : true,
            "services.instagram.profile_picture" : true
        }
    });
    return data;

});
```

If I understand Meteor's publish/subscribe mechanism correctly, this would push these fields for the entire user database to every client!  Clearly, this is not a sustainable solution.  Equally clearly, however, either I am  doing something wrong, or I am understanding something wrong.

Also: This unscalable solution works fine in a browser, but no avatar icons are visible when the app is deployed to a mobile device, for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: That does seem potentially unsustainable past a few thousand users. It may be better to store the data on the object you're showing the avatar with e.g. if you're showing something like forum posts you could store the userId, username and avatarUrl on each post. Downside being you'd possibly have to update every post with the new avatar url if the user changes their avatar. You could store the avatars on disk named as the MD5 hash of the userId and serve from your public folder or behind a better performing server like nginx, then just store userId and user name on each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the issue of which *fields* to publish from which *users* you want to publish data on.

Presumably you want to show avatars for other users that the current user is interacting with. You need to decide what *query* to use in

```
Meteor.users.find(query,{fields: {...}});
```

so that you narrow down the list from all users to just pertinent ones.

In my [app](https://cloak.ly) I end up using [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) to publish the users that are related to the current user via an intermediate collection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and the tip about reywood:publish-composite.  My question was specifically in relation to utilities:avatar, which does not appear to have any mechanism to filter users.  We finally decided to remove utilities:avatar data and rewrite the whole avatar handling manually.  I still don't understand how utilities:avatar is meant to work in a production environment with more than a few thousand users.

Comment: My sense is that query was just provided as an example. There's no reason you can't do `Meteor.users.find({ some actual query },{ fields: the list they give you })` to restrict the users you return.

Answer (score 0):

The unscalability of utilities:avatar seems, as far as I can tell, to be a real issue, and there isn't much to be done about it except to remove utilities:avatar and rewrite the avatar URL-fetching code by hand.

As for the avatars not appearing on mobile devices, the answer was simply that we needed to grant permission to access remote URLs in mobile-config.js, like this:

```
App.accessRule("http://*");
App.accessRule("https://*");
```